# When does Chameleon clustering fail?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

What is an example where the Chameleon clustering algorithm [1] fails to merge two clusters where it seems, with visual inspection (assuming the data is in two dimensions), that they should have been merged?

[1] Karypis, George, Eui-Hong Han, and Vipin Kumar. "Chameleon: Hierarchical clustering using dynamic modeling." Computer 32.8 (1999): 68-75.

Comment: The real question is: does Chamaeleon actually exist/work?

Comment: @Anony-Mousse What do you mean?

Comment: It's not available anywhere.

Comment: Could a method with more than 2000 citations have no online implementation?

Comment: Yes, if it has an interesting enough idea and good marketing, and was early enough in the field. I believe some "Chamaeleon data sets" are available, and that can be cited, too.